# SSRS Custom code error

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am using a custom code for text box background which I got here :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/02/16/sql-reporting-how-to-conditional-color-14-the-basics-report-expressions-custom-code/

However when I want to use it in an report expression I get a red error line under the function name. I am using Visual Studio and VB.NET.

What am i missing? I have pasted the code in the code under report properties.

Regards

EDIT :

I have used the following code as an expression : =code.ColorRYG(Fields!BlokkeklaarPersentGelewerKultAliasnaam.Value,Fields!BlokkeklaarmaksimumKultAliasnaam.Value,Fields!BlokkeklaarminimumKultAliasnaam.Value,0) 
A red squigly line appears under ColorRYG. The code I have pasted (Report Properties Code) is as follows :

```
Public Function ColorRYG(ByVal Value As Decimal, ByVal MaxPositive As Decimal, ByVal MaxNegative As Decimal, ByVal Neutral As Decimal) As String
    'Example: =code.ColorBack(expression, Max(expression), Min(expression), 0)
    '=code.colorback( Fields!Sales.Value,max( Fields!Sales.Value),min( Fields!Sales.Value),0)
    'Find Largest Range
    Dim decRange As Decimal
    Dim decPosRange As Decimal = Math.Abs(MaxPositive - Neutral)
    Dim decNegRange As Decimal = Math.Abs(MaxNegative - Neutral)

    decRange = IIf(decPosRange > decNegRange, decPosRange, decNegRange)

    'Force color into Max-Min Range. Important if you want to Clip the color display to a subset of the data range. 
    Value = Switch((Value > MaxPositive), MaxPositive, Value < MaxNegative, MaxNegative, True, Value) 
    'Find Delta required to change color by 1/255th of a shade
    Dim decColorInc As Decimal = 255 / decRange

    'Find appropriate color shade
    Dim iColor As Integer = CInt(Math.Round((Value - Neutral) * decColorInc))

    'Return Appropriate +ve or -ve color
    Dim strColor As String
    If iColor >= 0 Then
        'Green
        iColor = 255 - iColor 'Thus 0 = White & 255 = Green
        strColor = "#" & iColor.ToString("X2") & "FF00"
    Else
        'Red
        iColor = iColor + 255  'NB iColour is -ve;  -1 - -255 
        strColor = "#FF" & Math.Abs(iColor).ToString("X2") & "00"
    End If
    Return strColor
End Function
```

Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code you have used rather than a link to an article!

Comment: Thank you MiguelH. I have edited my question. Regards

Comment: You can ignore the red squiggly line. SSRS doesn't recognise the function name aftef '=code.' (go figure!) but it should work if the values passed to it are correct.

Comment: Thank you. There was a error in my data (the min and max were NULL). However when I fixed this only the color string is shown in my report (eg #AFF00).